# Admob invalid click activity

Tags: admob

If a person I don´t know, who lives far away from me, clicks on my ads all day long, can my Admob account be suspended? Does this scenario counts as invalid click activity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes your account can be disabled due to invalid click activity, if its accidental clicks place your ads somewhere the user wont click them by accident if its someone doing it on purpose you should probably implement a technique to avoid click abuse something like adding an addListener to your AdView and catching clicks of the AdView so you can remove the AdView for 1 hour for example if it is clicked more than 3x in a certain period etc, all depends on your needs. 
For more info you can check out Google's documentation on ad click abuse and how to prevent it : [Admob click abuse](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342099?hl=en)

Comment: I know your answer is old, but I'm wondering the same thing. Do you think one would be safe disabling ads for one hour if said as is clicked three times? Would you disable all ads or just that ad unit? Thanks.

Comment: having gotten my account suspended, I am doing something drastic, I'm disabling clicking on Banner Ads. Ads will still be shown, but since I'm putting a clear overlay on top of the banner, this makes it un-clickable.