# i made my play store developer console and admob account but how i care of invalid click

Tags: android, console, admob

i am new in play store developer console and adMob any one can give advise
about what type care we should do to make real success in admob and which place should i used my account & it is safe to use any where account of play store and 
publish apps and which one is owner main internet ip-address that to know that account created there

Comment: Hi, see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37504178/5241603

Comment: but how can know which area for tester device..? and which area for user to click on ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to Google Ads, from the documentation:

```
public AdRequest.Builder addTestDevice (String deviceId)
```

Causes a device to receive test ads. The deviceId can be obtained by viewing the logcat output after creating a new ad. For emulators, use DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR.
for example my Test Device id displayed in LogCat is `"B86BC9402SOMETHINLIKETHIS6BC57F7D3063F"`:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder() 
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("B86BC9402SOMETHINLIKETHIS6BC57F7D3063F")
        .build();
```

Comment: But how to know that is tester device or not

Comment: You have to add manually the test devices.You can add multiple test devices

Comment: hello if i have 2 wifi router with one internet connect  so i  login a/c in 1st one and not in second and i will use my apps second wifi router that have any problem..?

Comment: They track ip to which you are conneted and device address and almost everything eventually they come to know that there is been unintentional click and result too blocking your account
The Best way to avoid is only to add devices as Test Devices

Comment: i was created my a/c from my laptop from another place and i was that a/c through share invitation google play developer console Account to my personal a/c so if have any problem with that i login it my home with same laptop  and i use my device without  adding Test device so it is safe..? and it always login in my phone && "the two wifi router at my home"